# Tuleap - When i open artifact to update i have this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined"

Tags: tuleap

Tuleap - When i open artifact to update i have this javscript error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined". 
I cannot edit the artifact fields. 
Tuleap version is 7.7

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the javascript combine file you'll find under `/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/scripts/combined/`. This file will be automatically regenerated by Tuleap.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same Issue when try to add a Burndown Chart Field

.../plugins/tracker/?tracker=42&func=admin-formElements 500 (Internal Server Error)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined {stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined"}

deleting combined script not helps

Version
7.7.99.22

Upgrading to 7.8.99.7 helped